# Use plugin code in QGIS python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

I would like to write a Python script in QGIS and would like to use functions from a plugin.
For example, QuickOSM plugin has an import function and an "Open" button, that creates a temporary file in QGIS with the result of importing the osm file.
I would like my script to perform the same for more files within a folder.
I would also like the script to add a new field in the resulting file with the name of the file.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the available QGIS processing algorithms included in QuickOSM plugin e.g https://github.com/ThomasG77/QuickOSM/blob/update-processing-docs/doc/readme.md (Done a PR but not merged at the moment)

You may look at https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console to understand how to call the algorithms from PyQGIS

By combining both resources, you should be able to achieve what you asked for. The part about adding a new field can be managed separately from calling the Quick OSM processing algorithms.